# Installation process of Gzip framework in Swift

Tags: installation, swift3, gzip

How to install the Gzip framework in swift 3.0.1 and also how to use it in swift 3 and iOS 10.

For This actually they given the following instructions like

1.Build Gzip framework.

2.In Build Phases, add Gzip.framework library to your project.

3.import Gzip in your Swift file.

4.Use in your code.

But among all steps How to implement the 1st step like building the Gzip framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift

Comment: how to execute the 1st step like Building the particular framework.

Answer (score 0):

1.For the solution, Just download the project from the GitHub and then open it.

2.Now in the project navigator panel expand the folder named "product".

3.In that folder beneath you can see the Gzip.framework in red color, on that you right click in order to see it in the Finder.

4.From that Finder location, you just drag and drop into your project.

5.In General tab under linker and binaries you add the framework.

6.And finally import the header module like "import GZip"for required class and then implement the required things.